# Scrape website links in R

Tags: r, rvest, rselenium

Using either rvest or RSelenium when you scrape the links in R, you are able to do it by defining the begining part of HTML code, e.g. a href within given node. What if I face 2 following links:

`<a href="some_link" data-tracking="click_body" data-tracking-data='{"touch_point_button":"photo"}' data-featured-tracking="listing_no_promo">`

`<a href="some_link" data-tracking="click_body" data-tracking-data='{"touch_point_button":"photo"}' data-featured-tracking="listing_promo">`

As you may see they differ just with very last part. Do you know how can I grab(define) only links with promo /no promo?

Comment: Try SelectorGadget: http://selectorgadget.com/

Comment: Unfortunately it does not help

Comment: what is the website you are scrapping?

Comment: Polish website with property ads, here is sample link:
https://www.otodom.pl/sprzedaz/mieszkanie/?page=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `xpath` and `XML` library:
Assuming that you are looking for the no_promo links:

```
library(XML)
library(httr)
response <- GET(yourLink)
parsedoc <- htmlParse(response)
xpathSApply(parsedoc, "//a[@data-featured-tracking='listing_no_promo']", xmlGetAttr, "href")
```

or if you just looking for those links which contains keyword "no_promo" in data-featured-tracking parameter, then the last part would be like:

```
xpathSApply(parsedoc, "//a[contains(@data-featured-tracking, 'no_promo')]", xmlGetAttr, "href")
```

Answer (score 1):

So let's define `links` to be your object containing the html strings, e.g.

```
 links <- html_children(read_html("https://www.otodom.pl/sprzedaz/mieszkanie/"))
```

Then you can use regular expressions to match "promo"/"no_promo" within those strings, see

```
p1 <- grepl("promo", links, fixed = TRUE)
p1
[1] TRUE TRUE
p2 <- grepl("no_promo", links, fixed = TRUE)
p2
[1] FALSE  TRUE
```

So `links[p1]` contains all strings containing "promo" (so "no_promo" as well) and `links[p2]` contains all strings containing "no_promo". Now all that remains is to subset:

```
promo <- links[p1-p2] # contains strings with promo but not with no_promo
no.promo <- links[p2] # contains strings with no_promo
```

Comment: Any idea how extract link from such snippet of code by touch_point_button":"photo"  ---> structure seems to be the same, however solution proposed above does not seem to work:




<a href="www.website.com"
            data-tracking="click_body" data-tracking-data='{"touch_point_button":"photo"}'
            data-featured-name="listing_no_promo"        >